# Chemistry of Stripper Poles: How much weight can different materials support?

Tags: materials, plastics

I'm looking to create a light up dancing pole. This requires a **translucent** material that is strong enough to support the weight and force of a human being, even when it's hollowed out to so LEDs can go inside.  The material must also be reasonably affordable, so something like diamond is out of the question.

I've discovered a couple materials during my research (please recommend any I'm leaving out):

- acrylic (I know there are acrylic poles out there, but I'm not sure
  if they're able to support a human when hollowed out)
- polycarbonate

To take the example of polycarbonate, how much weight can it support as a function of its thickness/diameter?

[Also, if the editors feel like this is an inappropriate question I'd just like to point out that the weight that different materials can support is a very appropriate question here.  My intent is not to scandalize, only to build a dance pole and learn some Chemistry in the process.  Thank you]

Comment: I'm inclined to flag the question as off-topic. A question on the pros and cons of sex toy surface materials (silicone vs PVC, etc.) woud be more on-topic. One aspect related to chemistry is the possible update of body fluids by the pole material - changing performers change act differently "intense". The major part, however, is pure mechanics (and material science): bending moment of a tube of particular length that cannot exceed a certain diameter: the girls typically don't have hands the size of toilet lids ;) It's therefore not astonishing that the tubes are typically made of steel.

Comment: I think that a good (programmable) stage lighting, using high-power leds, will probably lead to better results (and higher tips).

Comment: Anyway: Welcome to Chemistry.SE! And yes, I upvoted your question because the idea is funny and not scandalizing at all!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is more related to mechanics and engineering.

Comment: Hmm, I think there *is* some chemistry in this, but it's way more appropriate in engineering.SE.

Comment: I'm fine with moving the question to Engineering